# Terminating android ASE shell from within the script

Tags: python, android, ase

I'm using android scripting environment with python (ASE), and I'd like to terminate the shell executing the script when the script terminates.
Is there a good way to do this?

I have tried executing on the last line:
os.system( 'kill %d' % os.getppid() )

but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `android.exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the above answer ought to be `android.Android().exit()`